# Transforming a polytope into vertex cones

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Is it possible to transform any polytope into vertex cones? A paper in French is often cited for this transformation, and I can't understand French.
[Points entiers dans les polyèdres convexes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~deloera/MISC/BIBLIOTECA/trunk/Brion/Brionsurveypointentiers.pdf)

I do not know whether it is only possible for some certain types of polytopes or any polytopes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The paper you cite is "Integer points in convex polytopes", and polytopes there have rational coordinates, AFAIK. But surely, you can define the tangent cones (and in particular vertex cones) for any polytope, without any extra conditions, see e.g. the [book by Beck and Robins](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tofDpuuEDu4C&lpg=PA174&dq=%22vertex%20cone%22%20polytope&pg=PA159#v=onepage&q=%22vertex%20cone%22%20polytope&f=false).